# powershell script not providing output

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

When I run this script to look at old log files it doesnt provide any output and that data is in the file.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\test\ -Recurse |
ForEach-Object {
"Parsing $($_.FullName)`r`n"
{
  Get-WinEvent userid=JDOE -FilterHashtable @{
    logname   = Logname=$_.Fullname
    id        = 4624, 4634, 4674
    userid    = JDOE
    Path      = $_.FullName
    Level     = 2
    StartTime = "4/1/16"
    EndTime   = "6/20/2016"
  } -EA Stop
} 
     }
```

Comment: Remove the logname entry, you're already providing the file via Path

Comment: that did help a bit but its running incredibly fast to think that is actually looking into the logs.  However with your help it is looking at ever file.  Do I have to direct output to some kind of file?